# Как можно внести list в цикл

Tags: python, парсер, list, бот, for

Написал бота для телеграма с использованием парсинга. Бот сейчас берет с нужного мне сайта 4 hrefа т.е. 4 ссылки и выводит их. Мне надо сделать что бы бот перед каждой ссылкой которую он выводит приписывал разный текст из списка [Weapon , ability , armor,ring].

Пример :

Weapon : ссылка1

Ability : ссылка2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzMOQ.png - как он сейчас выводит

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsRFG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1bv2.png - как надо что бы было

Comment: Перечитайте свой вопрос. Подумайте, вы сами его понять в состоянии? Потом поведайте нам, какого ответа вы ожидаете? Как цикл писать? Как список обозначать? Но предварительно задам вопрос -  а вы хоть один учебничек, хоть пару страничек про Python прочли перед тем как начать ботов писать? А перед тем как задать вопрос на форуме попробовали сами найти ответ на свой вопрос?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: все , изменил вопрос

Comment: Так что, вам надо рассказать, как работать со списком? Или как цикл сделать? Конкретику вопроса дайте!

Answer (score 0):

Занесите тексты и ссылки в массивы и обращайтесь к ним по индексу.

```
for i in range(<Длина>):
    print(f"{<Первый список>[i]}: {<Второй список>[i]}")
```

Вместо `print` используйте метод для вывода ботом сообщения.